# Drawing concentric shapes in an empty area with WPF

Tags: wpf, geometry, 2d

I am using WPF, and need to print some short strings on an engraving printer... The problem is that they need to be printed in "high" and all the blank space must be dug away, so I need to fill all the blank space with concentric shapes depending on the string being sent, something like this image:

[image: Screenshot]

I really don't know where to begin, could someone please point me in the right direction? Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might find some useful information here: http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/emcinfo.pl?Simple_EMC_G-Code_Generators

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a WPF specific way to accomplish it easily. I mean, short of pre-determining shapes for each character to draw and manually coding it...

However, can you use a custom font? If you can, why don't you make your own font with those shapes baked in, and reduce the character spacing to 0, no margins?